# Converting C Struct to Swift Struct

Tags: swift, struct

I have the following structure in a C program I am trying to convert to Swift:

```
struct record 
    {   int r;
        int c;
        int val;
        struct record *next;
    };
```

Swift won't allow a pointer (reference) to the structure within itself.
The way the C code works allows each record to contain a pointer to the next record for easy iteration through the records.

Is there a way to force this to work using UnsafeMutablePointer or something?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Make it a `class` type ...

Comment: What @Martin R said. From the Swift-documentation: "Structures are always copied when they are passed around in your code..."

Comment: You can also use an "indirect enum", see https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/07/26/linked-lists-enums-value-types-and-identity/ for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Swift won't allow a pointer (reference) to the structure within itself.

That's right. However, it allows a reference to an optional `class`:

```
class record {
    var r : Int = 0
    var c : Int = 0
    var val : Int = 0
    var next : record? = nil
};
```

That is what you need: since `next` pointer is allowed to be `NULL` in C, you should be able to set it to `nil` in Swift.

Comment: @Mr.UB I would use a class. `struct` would require mutability markers all over the place, making objects harder to use.

Comment: If this answer were a struct, wouldn't that actually make a copy of the next record, and not just a reference to it?

Comment: The current class won't compile without either default values or an initializer...

Comment: @T.BenjaminLarsen Thanks!

Comment: Thank you guys!...I will try the class idea...seems like a decent solution, thank you for the ENUM example as well....also looks interesting.

Comment: Oh, OK, Thank you...didn't know how the sword...I appreciate the feedback...The class approach is working for me!...